# how to get information from tag <a>'s action-data?

Tags: javascript, flask

I want to put some information in the "action-data" of a href, like:

```
 <a href=# action-data="userid={{g.user._id}}&amp;messageid={{message._id}}" id=reply >reply</a>
```

but how to get the userid & messageid back to Javascript code?

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function () {
    $('a#reply').bind('click', function () {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_replies', {
            messageid: ??????How to get messageid from href action-data?
            userid: ??????How to get userid from href action-data?
        }, function (data) {
        $('#replies').text(data.result)
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you control the markup? I.e. can you format it any way you want?

Comment: yes, i'm modifing Flask's minitwit example code, i control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store it differently:

```
<a href="#"data-userid="{{g.user._id}}" data-messageid="{{message._id}}" id="reply">reply</a>
```

jQuery can get it like this:

```
 var messageId = $('#reply').data('messageid');
```

Also, the click event can be much shorter:

```
$('a#reply').click(function(){

});
```

ps: remember to use quotes, as you didn't in `href` and `id`

Comment: :Thanks very much. BTW, I'm not using quotes because flask doesn't neither, it seems a HTML5 feature, doesn't it?

Comment: @BrentJiang: That's correct, quotes are not strictly required. If you have values with certain characters, they are, so it's still a good practice. Or as Mark Pilgrim says: [Always quote your attribute values unless you’re a rockstar.](http://diveintohtml5.info/peeks-pokes-and-pointers.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you control the markup, you should prefix attributes with `data-`, not suffix them with `-data`. Also, it seems easier to have one attribute for each property, instead of parsing, so why not:

```
<a href=# data-userid="{{g.user._id}}" data-messageid="{{ message._id }}" id=reply>
```

Then you can use jQuery `data`:

```
var userid = $("a#reply").data("userid"),
    messageid = $("a#reply").data("messageid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the other answerer's recommendations about using different markup. However, if you can't change the markup you can parse the parameters like this:

```
...
$('a#reply').click(function() {
    // parse the 'action-data' attribute of the link
    var actionData = $(this).attr('action-data');
    var params = {};
    $.each(actionData.split("&"), function(index, data) {
        var keyValue = data.split("=");
        params[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    });

    // now you can use params.userid and params.messageid
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, your answer's very useful, but i don't have enough reputation, :(